# SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found

Tags: php, simplexml

The code below (using CodeIgniter 3.0) is giving this error, and I don't understand why:

> SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found

```
<?php

require_once './pdfGenerator.php';
require_once './pdfWrapper.php';
require_once './tcpdf_ext.php';
$debug = false;
$error_handler = set_error_handler("PDFErrorHandler");

if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $xmlString = stripslashes($_POST['mycoolxmlbody']);
} else {
    $xmlString = $_POST['mycoolxmlbody'];
}
//where the problem

if ($debug == true) {
    error_log($xmlString, 3, 'debug_'.date("Y_m_d__H_i_s").'.xml');
}

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$scPDF = new schedulerPDF();
$scPDF->printScheduler($xml);
function PDFErrorHandler ($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    global $xmlString;
    if ($errno < 1024) {
        echo $errstr."<br>";
        error_log($xmlString, 3, 'error_report_'.date("Y_m_d__H_i_s").'.xml');
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: The content of $xmlString doesn't seems to be valid XML. Have you checked that.

Comment: You should provide us with the contents of `$xmlString` if we were to help you. but it looks like you can solve thath yourslef

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString,'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

instead of

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString,LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

Comment: Or, since `LIBXML_NOCDATA` is irrelevant to most people's use of SimpleXML other than some debugging confusion, just `$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);` I don't think that was the problem in this question, though, since the error message was about the content of the XML, not the options passed.